# Can multiple LC circuits be connected to the same antenna to listen to different frequencies all at once?

Tags: ac, radio, resonance

I am very new to this. I am trying to make a radio that listens to multiple stations at once and signal processing circuit that separates frequencies from a microphone signal.

Comment: Look up Bragg crystals. This technique has been used for decades.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but there will be interaction between the circuits. For example, if you were to directly connect two capacitors of two tuned circuits in parallel, the result would be the sum of the two capacitances. To tune multiple frequencies requires some isolation mechanism, e.g. resistors between each tuned circuit.

It depends on how far apart the frequencies are, as well. For example, two FM broadcast stations just a few hundred MHz could be amplified by a single *broadly-tuned* front end (RF amplifier) connected to the antenna, mixed with a signal from a local oscillator, and then fed to *two* intermediate-frequency amplifiers and detectors. The audio output could then be mixed and sent to a single audio amplifier.

Comment: Would I have to use a detector for each frequency I want to detect or can I use an upper limit LC and lower limit LC and measure the amplitude difference to find the frequencies in between ( I am trying to detect the full range of human hearing but don’t want 19,980 LC detectors (one for each frequency)). It would be way better if I could just use two and measure the difference in resonance.

Comment: If you're trying to measure a large range of frequencies, use a **sweep generator** to produce an audio signal staring at perhaps 10 Hz (we can *feel* low-frequency sound in the abdomen) and extending to 20 kHz.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use discrete L & C components, you will get all possible resonances. Depending on Qs, you may or may not be able to detect these resonances.

Comment: What are Qs? I am new to this.